# Change log language Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, logging

I have an application run in a Windows machine, and the language of this machine is in **Frensh**, my application use PostgreSQL, and when I see the log of errors, I find that the language is in **Frensh**:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: authentification par mot de passe ▒chou▒e pour l'utilisateur  ▒ postgres ▒ (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
```

I tried to set Locale in the main method, but it not work :

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "EN"));
```

Is there any way to change this log to be in **English** language?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization I believe here you can find the solution. Adding an interceptor bean solved my problem before.